# C++ - How to run a class in separate thread and reference functions from same class in main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have this:

```
class VibraniumEngine {
public:
    VibraniumEngine(VibraniumEngine const &) = delete;
    VibraniumEngine(VibraniumEngine &&) = delete;

    VibraniumEngine& operator= (VibraniumEngine const&) = delete;
    VibraniumEngine& operator= (VibraniumEngine&&) = delete;

    static VibraniumEngine* instance()
    {
        static VibraniumEngine instance;
        return &instance;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        while(true){
            // Do stuff
        }
    }

    void Run();
};

#define sVibraniumEngine VibraniumEngine::instance()

int main()
{
    std::thread vibraniumEngineThread (&VibraniumEngine::Start, sVibraniumEngine);

    //How can I call here method `Run` as if it was called from `vibraniumEngineThread` context ?
}
```

This creates a new thread of class `VibraniumEngine` and main thread continues execution.

Function `VibraniumEngine::Start` holds `while` loop.

Vibranium engine has other public variables and methods rather than just `Start`.

Is there a way to call these methods from the main thread as if they were called from `vibraniumEngineThread`, aka in the context of the created thread, not from the main thread?

Comment: You can call things on `sVibraniumEngine` in main, and that will affect the `sVibraniumEngine` that is in thread since it is a singleton.  Do you have some code that you are trying to get to work that isn't working?  Still kind of unclear to me what your actual issue is.

Comment: We need to fix the terminology here, you can't "run" a class. Also there is no thread "of class VibraniumEngine" created, you are starting a thread that executes the `Start` member function of the class `VibraniumEngine` on the static instance declared in the `instance()` member function. And what do you mean by "context of created thread"? That being said, please clarify what you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to call these methods from the main thread as if they were called from `vibraniumEngineThread`, aka in the context of the created thread, not from the main thread?

Not directly, no. You would have to setup your own queuing system, where the main thread can push requests into the queue, and then the worker thread pulls out requests from the queue and executes them as needed.

For example:

```
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>

class VibraniumEngine {
public:
    VibraniumEngine(VibraniumEngine const &) = delete;
    VibraniumEngine(VibraniumEngine &&) = delete;

    VibraniumEngine& operator= (VibraniumEngine const&) = delete;
    VibraniumEngine& operator= (VibraniumEngine&&) = delete;

    static VibraniumEngine* instance()
    {
        static VibraniumEngine instance;
        return &instance;
    }

    class Request
    {
    public:
        virtual void DoAction() = 0;
    };
    using RequestPtr = std::unique_ptr<Request>;

    void Start()
    {
        while (true){
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);

                if (!m_requests.empty()) {
                    std::queue<RequestPtr> l_requests;
                    l_requests.swap(m_requests);
                    lk.unlock();

                    while (!l_requests.empty()) {
                        RequestPtr request = std::move(l_requests.front());
                        l_requests.pop();
                        request->DoAction();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Do Other Stuff...
        }
    }

    void Run() { ... }

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void AddRequest(Args&&... args)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        m_requests.push(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

private:
    std::queue<RequestPtr> m_requests;
    std::mutex m_lock;
};

#define sVibraniumEngine VibraniumEngine::instance()

class CallVibraniumEngineRun : public VibraniumEngine::Request
{
public:
    void DoAction() override {
        sVibraniumEngine->Run();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::thread vibraniumEngineThread (&VibraniumEngine::Start, sVibraniumEngine);
    ...
    sVibraniumEngine->AddRequest<CallVibraniumEngineRun>();
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of such queuing system ?

Comment: @Venelin There is no one single way to accomplish it, there are many different designs you could go with, depending on your particular needs. But I have updated my answer with one possible example.